# Best Linear Predictor Assumptions

Tags: regression, linear-model, prediction

Chapter 6 of *Plane Answers to Complex Questions, 4th Edition* motivates linear regression through the lens of best prediction. Unfortunately, I'm confused about some assumptions in deriving the best *linear* predictor.

It's not too hard to show $\hat y(x):=\mathbb E[y|x]$ is the best predictor with respect to the mean squared error, but since this is hard to compute in general, the author restricts attention to a linear approximation of $\hat y(x)$. The linear approximation only requires knowledge of means, variances, and covariances of $x$ and $y$.

Let $V_{xx}:=\text{cov}(x)$ and $V_{xy}:=\text{cov}(x,y)$. The author starts,

> Let $\beta_*$ be a solution to $V_{xx}\beta=V_{xy}$, then we will show that the function
>   $$
> \mu_y+(x-\mu_x)^\top\beta_*
> $$
>   is the best linear predictor of $y$ based on $x$.

Why is the initial line "Let $\beta_*$ be a solution to $V_{xx}\beta=V_{xy}$" required? This implies $\mathscr C(V_{xy})\subseteq\mathscr C(V_{xx}),$ but I don't see what this provides.

Comment: Would you be able to show that the function is the best linear predictor of $y$ based on $x$ if $\beta_*$ were *not* a solution to $V_{xx}\beta = V_{xy}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show this with a little bit of algebra. Because the statement,

$y = \mu_y + (x - \mu_x)^\top\beta$    $\hspace{1cm}$(1)

can be easily written in a way that gives $V_{xx}\beta = V_{xy}$. 
 From (1), we have

$E[(x-\mu_x)(y - \mu_y)] = E[(x - \mu_x)(x - \mu_x)^\top]\beta$    $\hspace{1cm}$(2)

and the rest follows by construction. In other words, solving the optimization with constraint (1) is identical with solving the optimization with constraint (2). It's just a matter of which one you want to use to frame your problem.

Comment: Interesting, so through (2), we're framing the problem as we want the covariance $\text{cov}(x,y)$ to be a linear combination of $\text{cov}(x)$?

Comment: Yes, that's another implication. I guess it's just easier to think of representing $y$ as a linear combination of $x - \mu_x$'s. But using (2) gives the less relatable result (at least in my view) that you point out.